# image indexing using discrete wavelet transform in matlab

Tags: matlab

I did a function in matlab that implements the concept of indexing image using discrete wavelet transform but I need to know if there is in matlab a predefined function that do the same functionality

Thanks in advance,

Hassan.

Comment: Have you looked at `dwt` or `dwt2` ?

Comment: actually I didn't use it, I implemented the algorithm of the discrete wavelet transform and the thing that I'm not sure about the results of the indexing that I got, it seems does not work properly or I dont understand what type of results should I get when I use the DWT indexing

Comment: here is my code : https://www.dropbox.com/s/jr6tg88w56b5uds/TestProject.7z

Comment: actually I didn't use it, I implemented the algorithm of the discrete wavelet transform and the thing is I'm not sure about the results of the indexing that I got, it seems does not work properly or I dont understand what type of results should I get when I use the DWT indexing